# redux update state value without changing initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a state that looks like:

```
{data: Object
    names: Array[4]
    value: null
}
```

In my reducers I want to update like:

```
case types.VALUE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {data: {value: action.value}})
```

Here it is updating the whole `data` object but I only want to update value.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Object.assign again to keep the original keys from data like

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    data: Object.assign({}, state.data, {value: action.value})
})
```